# Add label to "implies"

Tags: labels

I'm new in Latex and I don't know how to write this:
[image: this relation]
How can I do this? I know that the implies is written like this $\to$ but I want to add that alpha on top.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Loading `amamath`, use `\xrightarrow{\alpha}`.

Comment: @Bernard To clarify, I think you mean `amsmath`.

Comment: @Gaussler: Oh! yes. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 0):

\stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow}

Comment: `$$...$$` should never be used with LaTeX.

Comment: why $$...$$ should never be used with LaTeX?

Comment: [Therefore](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/19809).